# Histogram function using Dynamic arrays C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, histogram, dynamic-arrays

My program runs to ask for user input of a specified integer followed by storing more integers in a dynamic array. The output gives out a histogram uses stars to show how many of each integer.

I have every task completed except for one. I have tried implementing a swap function for hours but could not figure out a solution to my problem.

My problem is that I want to get my output in order from least to greatest.
For example,

`Enter number of grades:
5
Enter grades (each on a new line):
20
4
10
10
20 
Histogram:
 20 **
  4 *
 10 **`

However, I want the following output instead

`Histogram:
  4 *
 10 **
 20 **`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void hist(int arr[], int n);

void swap(int &a, int &b);

int main(){
  int* arr = NULL;
  int number;
  cout << "Enter number of grades:" << endl;
  cin >> number;

  cout << "Enter grades (each on a new line):" << endl;
  arr = new int[number];
  for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
  }
  hist(arr, number);
  return 0;
  delete [] arr;
}

void hist(int arr[], int n){
  cout << "Histogram:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
      if(arr[i] == arr[j])
        break;
    if (i == j){
      int xx = count(arr, arr+n, arr[i]);
      cout << setw(3) << arr[i] << " ";
      for (int j = 0; j < xx; ++j){
        cout << "*";
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
}

void swap(int &a, int &b){
  int temp;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

Comment: see [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). You are `using namespace std;` so you're adding to `std::swap`s overload set. Have you tried calling your swap function from a simpler function to see if that's what's actually giving you problems? Also stop doing this: `int x; x = 1;` and just do `int x = 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to sort the vector before counting the elements.

```
void hist(int arr[], int n){
  sort(arr, arr+n);
  ...
}
```

I would suggest you to change your solution. If you were using a `std::map` you would have the solution of your problem right there, in a preordered fashion. 
Also, why don't you use a `std::vector`?